# How can i solve No such label 'resetupdate' within the scope of the goto statement error?

Tags: c#, goto

I must use the this code in c#:

```
while(true){
    resetupdate:
    //somecode here
}
goto resetupdate;
```

But in line `goto resetupdate;` I get this error:

> No such label 'resetupdate' within the scope of the goto statement

How can I solve that problem? Or how can I call `resetupdate`?

Comment: You're not allowed to jump *into* the body of a control-flow statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can i use other way for that purpose?

Comment: We'd need to see a *more complete* example of what you're trying to do. I'm guessing that there's at least *some code* after the end of the `while` and that the `goto` isn't unconditional, as you've shown it here. Present us the *problem*, not your attempt at a solution with all context removed.

Comment: While `goto` has its areas of use, they are very small and rare. Learn to solve program-flow problems without goto's.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's probably a whole bunch of if's with breaks, that exit the not-so-infinite loop.

Comment: @atlaste - yes, but then they immediately try to jump back *into* the loop to make it more infinite? It's *possible* that they've found `break` but not `continue`, I suppose, but as I say, we really need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope with a '{' and ends with a '}' token. Because your label is inside a child scope, you cannot access it.

Obviously you can fix this using more, ugly goto's:

```
// YUCK YUCK YUCK!

start:
// some code
resetupdate:
//somecode here
// ... break becomes:
if (someCondition) { goto exitloop; }
//
goto start;
exitloop:
// your condition code...
goto resetupdate;
```

Not sure why you would want something like this though.... these types of goto constructions compile fine, but are utterly unreadable for other software developers.

---

Okay, let's look at the original question for a second shall we:

```
while(true){
    // **1
    resetupdate:
    //somecode here **2
}
goto resetupdate;
```

Now, I'm guessing here that `somecode` (**2) will emit a `break` somehow, otherwise this whole label/`goto` construct doesn't make any sense. So, getting back into the loop will be a matter of simply moving the resetupdate:

```
resetupdate:
while(true){
    //somecode here that uses break
}
goto resetupdate;
```

However, this doesn't solve the issues that will arise when **1 will also contain code. To do that, you can change the code to use more goto's and labels...

It's much better to avoid these kinds of constructions in the first place - but without more context information I cannot do that.

Comment: that is not a fix as it will never pass the first goto

Comment: @LeMoN.xaH It will pass just as fine as the `while(true)` in the original question.

Comment: @LeMoN.xaH Fine, I added some more info to the answer. It'll work fine, it's just ugly as hell.